# How to pulling actual data from multiple pages of website with using Selenium,Beautiful Soup ,Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, datatable

I am new for pulling data using Python . I want to do excel file as pulling tables from website.

```
The website url : "https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml"
```

In this webpage ,there are tables at seperately pages for hours data.Due to one hour includes around 500 datas so pages are divided. 
I want to pull all data for each hour.
But my mistake is pulling same table even if page changes.

I am using beautiful soup,pandas ,selenium libraries. I will show you my codes for explaning myself.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
metin =source.title.get_text()
source.find("input",attrs={"id":"j_idt206:txt1"})
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
tarih = source.find("input",attrs={"id":"j_idt206:date1_input"})["value"] 
import datetime
import time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
today = datetime.date.today()
# print(today)
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 1) 
tomorrow = str(tomorrow)
words = tarih.split('.')  
yeni_tarih = '.'.join(reversed(words))
yeni_tarih =yeni_tarih.replace(".","-")
def tablo_cek():
    tablo = source.find_all("table")#sayfadaki tablo 
    dfs = pd.read_html(str(tablo))#tabloyu dataframe e çekmek
    dfs.append(dfs)#tabloya yeni çekilen tabloyu ekle
    print(dfs)
    return tablo 
if tomorrow == yeni_tarih :
    print(yeni_tarih == tomorrow)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/tugba.ozkan/AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='96']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    user = driver.find_element_by_name("j_idt206:txt1")
    nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[@class ='ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next']")
    num=0
    while num < 24 :
        user.send_keys(num) #saate veri gönder 
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_idt206:goster').click() #saati uygula
        nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[@class ='ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next']")#o saatteki next page
        nextpage.click() #next page e geç 
        user = driver.find_element_by_name("j_idt206:txt1") #tekrar getiriyor saat yerini 
        time.sleep(1)
        tablo_cek()
        num = num + 1 #saati bir arttır
        user.clear() #saati sıfırla
else:
    print("Güncelleme gelmedi")
```

In this situation :

```
nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[@class ='ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next']")#o saatteki next page
            nextpage.click()
```

when python clicks the button to go to next page ,the next page show then it needs to pull next table as shown table. But it doesn't work.
At the output I saw appended table that is same values.Like this :
This is my output :

```
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0                0      25.0101   19.15990
1                1      24.9741   19.16390
2                2      24.9741   19.18510
3               85      24.9741   19.18512
4               86      24.9736   19.20762
5               99      24.9736   19.20763
6              100      24.6197   19.20763
7              101      24.5697   19.20763
8              300      24.5697   19.20768
9              301      24.5697   19.20768
10             363      24.5697   19.20770
11             364      24.5497   19.20770
12             400      24.5497   19.20771
13             401      24.5297   19.20771
14             498      24.5297   19.20773
15             499      24.5297   19.36473
16             500      24.5297   19.36473
17             501      24.4097   19.36473
18             563      24.4097   19.36475
19             564      24.3897   19.36475
20             999      24.3897   19.36487
21            1000      24.3097   19.36487
22            1001      24.1897   19.36487
23            1449      24.1897   19.36499, [...]]
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0                0      25.0101   19.15990
1                1      24.9741   19.16390
2                2      24.9741   19.18510
3               85      24.9741   19.18512
4               86      24.9736   19.20762
5               99      24.9736   19.20763
6              100      24.6197   19.20763
7              101      24.5697   19.20763
8              300      24.5697   19.20768
9              301      24.5697   19.20768
10             363      24.5697   19.20770
11             364      24.5497   19.20770
12             400      24.5497   19.20771
13             401      24.5297   19.20771
14             498      24.5297   19.20773
15             499      24.5297   19.36473
16             500      24.5297   19.36473
17             501      24.4097   19.36473
18             563      24.4097   19.36475
19             564      24.3897   19.36475
20             999      24.3897   19.36487
21            1000      24.3097   19.36487
22            1001      24.1897   19.36487
23            1449      24.1897   19.36499, [...]]
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0                0      25.0101   19.15990
1                1      24.9741   19.16390
2                2      24.9741   19.18510
3               85      24.9741   19.18512
4               86      24.9736   19.20762
5               99      24.9736   19.20763
6              100      24.6197   19.20763
7              101      24.5697   19.20763
8              300      24.5697   19.20768
9              301      24.5697   19.20768
10             363      24.5697   19.20770
11             364      24.5497   19.20770
12             400      24.5497   19.20771
13             401      24.5297   19.20771
14             498      24.5297   19.20773
15             499      24.5297   19.36473
16             500      24.5297   19.36473
17             501      24.4097   19.36473
18             563      24.4097   19.36475
19             564      24.3897   19.36475
20             999      24.3897   19.36487
21            1000      24.3097   19.36487
22            1001      24.1897   19.36487
23            1449      24.1897   19.36499, [...]]
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0                0      25.0101   19.15990
1                1      24.9741   19.16390
2                2      24.9741   19.18510
3               85      24.9741   19.18512
4               86      24.9736   19.20762
5               99      24.9736   19.20763
6              100      24.6197   19.20763
7              101      24.5697   19.20763
8              300      24.5697   19.20768
9              301      24.5697   19.20768
10             363      24.5697   19.20770
11             364      24.5497   19.20770
12             400      24.5497   19.20771
13             401      24.5297   19.20771
14             498      24.5297   19.20773
15             499      24.5297   19.36473
16             500      24.5297   19.36473
17             501      24.4097   19.36473
18             563      24.4097   19.36475
19             564      24.3897   19.36475
20             999      24.3897   19.36487
21            1000      24.3097   19.36487
22            1001      24.1897   19.36487
23            1449      24.1897   19.36499, [...]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will also offer up another solution as you can pull that data directly from the requests. It also gives you the option of how many to pull per page (and you can iterate through each page), however, if you set that limit high enough, you can get it all in 1 request. So there are about 400+ rows, I set the limit to 1000, then you only need page 0:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}

page = '0'
payload = {
'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true',
'javax.faces.source': 'j_idt206:dt',
'javax.faces.partial.execute': 'j_idt206:dt',
'javax.faces.partial.render': 'j_idt206:dt',
'j_idt206:dt': 'j_idt206:dt',
'j_idt206:dt_pagination': 'true',
'j_idt206:dt_first': page,
'j_idt206:dt_rows': '1000',
'j_idt206:dt_skipChildren': 'true',
'j_idt206:dt_encodeFeature': 'true',
'j_idt206': 'j_idt206',
'j_idt206:date1_input': '04.02.2021',
'j_idt206:txt1': '0',
'j_idt206:dt_rppDD': '1000'
}

rows = []
hours = list(range(0,24))
for hour in hours:
    payload.update({'j_idt206:txt1':str(hour)})
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.replace('![CDATA[',''), 'lxml')
    columns = ['Fiyat (TL/MWh)',    'Talep (MWh)',  'Arz (MWh)', 'hour']
    
    trs = soup.find_all('tr')
    for row in trs:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        data = [x.text for x in data] + [str(hour)]
        rows.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
    Fiyat (TL/MWh) Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0             0,00   25.113,70  17.708,10
1             0,01   25.077,69  17.712,10
2             0,02   25.077,67  17.723,10
3             0,85   25.076,57  17.723,12
4             0,86   25.076,05  17.746,12
..             ...         ...        ...
448         571,01   19.317,10  29.529,60
449         571,80   19.316,86  29.529,60
450         571,90   19.316,83  29.529,70
451         571,99   19.316,80  29.529,70
452         572,00   19.316,80  29.540,70

[453 rows x 3 columns]
```

To find this just takes a little investigative work. If you go to Dev Tools -> Network -> XHR, you try to see if the data is somewhere embedded in those requests (see image). If you find it there, go to `Headers` tab and you can get the url and parameters at the bottom.

MOST cases you'll see the data is returned in a nice json format. Not the case here. It was returned in a slightly different way with xml, so need a tad extra work to pull out the tags and such. But not impossible.

[image]

Comment: Wow so good! thanks so much but what is this ? what is the substructure of this codes ? Could you explain to me ,please ?

Comment: @TugbaOzkan, added it to the solution

Comment: actually I have one more question.. How can i do this all hours ? Any idea can't comes to my mind. I need to increase this part of payload : 'j_idt206:txt1': '0' . This zero mean is 00.00 am. I need to pull data for every hour in a day. How can i do ? Guide me ,please

Comment: @TugbaOzkan give it try.

Comment: I tried a lot of codes for hours datas but It doesn't work. 'j_idt206:txt1' value is clock value. I tried this way: I changed the value as 'j_idt206:txt1': '0' in payload. I used 'for' loop and I tried one by one in same time. .I wrote 1 instead of 0 for  'j_idt206:txt1' . But it pulled values for 0.00 pm. I can't out this .

Comment: I see what you mean. Ya I tried a few things too. Not sure why it won't pull it. you might have to use selenium in that case as for whatever reason it's not fetching with the parameter.

Comment: Yes thank you . Headers are very useful but I guess it doesn't work for special situations. Thanks for everything !

Answer (score 1):

That's because you pull the initial html here `source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")`, and then keep rendering that content.

You need to pull the html for each page that you go to. It's just a matter of adding 1 line. I commented where I added it:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
metin =source.title.get_text()
source.find("input",attrs={"id":"j_idt206:txt1"})
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
tarih = source.find("input",attrs={"id":"j_idt206:date1_input"})["value"] 
import datetime
import time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
today = datetime.date.today()
# print(today)
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 1) 
tomorrow = str(tomorrow)
words = tarih.split('.')  
yeni_tarih = '.'.join(reversed(words))
yeni_tarih =yeni_tarih.replace(".","-")
def tablo_cek():
    source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")  #<-- get the current html
    tablo = source.find_all("table")#sayfadaki tablo 
    dfs = pd.read_html(str(tablo))#tabloyu dataframe e çekmek
    dfs.append(dfs)#tabloya yeni çekilen tabloyu ekle
    print(dfs)
    return tablo 
if tomorrow == yeni_tarih :
    print(yeni_tarih == tomorrow)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/arz-talep.xhtml")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='96']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    user = driver.find_element_by_name("j_idt206:txt1")
    nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[@class ='ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next']")
    num=0
    
    tablo_cek() #<-- need to get that data before moving to next page
    while num < 24 :
        user.send_keys(num) #saate veri gönder 
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_idt206:goster').click() #saati uygula
        nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[@class ='ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next']")#o saatteki next page
        nextpage.click() #next page e geç 
        user = driver.find_element_by_name("j_idt206:txt1") #tekrar getiriyor saat yerini 
        time.sleep(1)
        tablo_cek()
        num = num + 1 #saati bir arttır
        user.clear() #saati sıfırla
else:
    print("Güncelleme gelmedi")
```

**Output:**

```
True
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0                0     25.11370   17.70810
1                1     25.07769   17.71210
2                2     25.07767   17.72310
3               85     25.07657   17.72312
4               86     25.07605   17.74612
..             ...          ...        ...
91           10000     23.97000   17.97907
92           10001     23.91500   17.97907
93           10014     23.91500   17.97907
94           10015     23.91500   17.97907
95           10100     23.91499   17.97909

[96 rows x 3 columns], [...]]
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0            10101     23.91499   18.04009
1            10440     23.91497   18.04015
2            10999     23.91493   18.04025
3            11000     23.89993   18.04025
4            11733     23.89988   18.04039
..             ...          ...        ...
91           23999     23.55087   19.40180
92           24000     23.55087   19.40200
93           24001     23.53867   19.40200
94           24221     23.53863   19.40200
95           24222     23.53863   19.40200

[96 rows x 3 columns], [...]]
[    Fiyat (TL/MWh)  Talep (MWh)  Arz (MWh)
0            24360     21.33871    19.8112
1            24499     21.33868    19.8112
2            24500     21.33868    19.8112
3            24574     21.33867    19.8112
4            24575     21.33867    19.8112
..             ...          ...        ...
91           29864     21.18720    20.3708
92           29899     21.18720    20.3708
93           29900     21.18720    20.3808
94           29999     21.18720    20.3808
95           30000     21.18530    20.3811

[96 rows x 3 columns], [...]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got it easily